# How do I preload a directive + corresponding HTML in Ionic/Angular? (Mapbox Directive)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mapbox

I want to preload a  containing my Angular directive for a plugin called Mapbox. Without this preload the user will, upon entering the page where the directive is, have to wait for mapbox to load into the directive.

I tried using the 'PreloadAllModules' attribute in the app-routing.module.ts file. I also tried implementing my own PreloadStrategy which looked like this:

app-routing-preloader-service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppRoutingPreloaderService implements PreloadingStrategy {

    private routesToPreload: RouteToPreload[] = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
        if (route.data && route.data.preload) {
            this.routesToPreload.push({
                routePath: route.path,
                route: route,
                load: load
            });
        }

        return of(null);
    }

    preloadRoute(path: string): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            if (this.routesToPreload && 
                this.routesToPreload.length > 0) {
                const routeToPreload: RouteToPreload = 
                    this.routesToPreload.find(
                       (filterRouteToPreload: RouteToPreload) =>
                       filterRouteToPreload.routePath === path);

                if (routeToPreload) {
                    routeToPreload.load();
                }
            }

            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

This is my directive which lies on a certain tab in the web application:

map.page.html:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:105%;" id="mapbox" appMapbox></div>
```

And this is the directive:

mapbox.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appMapbox]"
})
export class MapboxDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public el: ElementRef,
    public mapboxService: MapboxService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapboxService.init(this.el)
  }
}
```

I would like this directive and html page to be loaded just like when you enter the tab where the directive is but instead load it before entering the tab.

Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify, the issue here is that I want to run the MapboxService.init(Elementref el) on before-hand but I cant because it requires the html element that Mapbox should be show in and I dont have that until I enter the map.page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's tricky.

What I would do is create the map container in the `appComponent` so that it's loaded when you enter the app (or whever you deem it suited, I don't know your project enough to tell you where to put it).

Then, I would either hide it (`hidden` tag attribute) or display it out of the screen `position: absolute; left: -99999px;`).

When the user gets on the page, I would then place it where it belongs with absolute positioning.

But to be completely honest with you, I think this a hideous way of doing it, and instead I would simply display a loader for the user (waiting for the data to come isn't a bad thing). You could surround it with other data so that the user "has something to do" while waiting.